# сложная выборка в одном запросе mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Новостной личный сайт (в стадии разработки). Нажимая на пункт меню "Рубрики" пользователь должен увидеть таблицу - список категорий с указанием количества записей в каждой категории и дату последней записи. Это я сделал, получается типа этого:

[image: скрин]

Структура БД:
таблица "pages" содержит все записи. Основные поля:

```
id     - первичный ключ,
id_cat - идентификатор категории,
content - содержимое,
date    - дата внесения записи.
```

таблица "category" имеет два поля:

```
id_cat - идентификатор категории,
category - само текстовое название категории
```

Код:

```
SELECT c.id_cat, c.category, COUNT(p.id_cat), MAX(p.date)
FROM category AS c 
LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON c.id_cat=p.id_cat
GROUP BY c.id_cat
ORDER BY c.id_cat DESC
```

Хотелось бы сделать, чтобы дата последней публикации была активной ссылкой на соответствующую запись. Можно ли все это объединить в одном запросе, вытащив каким-то образом id публикации с MAX(p.date)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
c.id_cat, 
c.category, 
COUNT(p.id_cat), 
MAX(p.date),
(SELECT max(id) FROM pages WHERE id_cat=c.id_cat and date = MAX(p.date))
FROM category AS c 
LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON c.id_cat=p.id_cat
GROUP BY c.id_cat
ORDER BY c.id_cat DESC
```

Примерно так. В общем в разделе SELECT еще подразпрос напишите. Ведь вы для этой строки знаете ID_категории и максимальную дату публикации, значит вам нужно вытащить туда максимальный ID публикации на эту дату.

Comment: Или даже так... просто налету сложно сказать сразу верно )))
SELECT
  d.*,
 (SELECT max(p.id) FROM pages p WHERE p.id_cat = o.id_cat and date = o.mdate)
FROM
 (
  SELECT 
  c.id_cat, 
  c.category, 
  COUNT(p.id_cat) as col, 
  MAX(p.date) as mdate
  FROM category AS c 
  LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON c.id_cat=p.id_cat
  GROUP BY c.id_cat
  ORDER BY c.id_cat DESC
 ) d

Comment: два вложенных select ??

Comment: Ну да, а что тут такого. Если правильно строить, то они быстро работают и без проблем. А в сложных ситуациях без позапросов не обойтись.
И по максимуму желательно стараться избегать конструкций JOIN - при большом количестве этих конструкций запросы могут в разы дольше выполняться.
Подходить к запросу надо с той же логики что и к программированию - только пишутся запросы сверху-вниз.
Сервер всегда сначала обрабатывает самый вложенный подзапрос, т.к. он является условием для вышестоящего. Поэтому если как можно быстрее написать выполнение подзапросов, то вся конструкция будет выполняться быстро.

Comment: IvanZakirov, в моем случае без join не обойтись, не так ли?

Comment: можно и обойтись. Но будет ли это иметь больший толк в данном случае, не знаю. надо писать и смотреть не время выполнения запроса. JOIN в данном случае, можно заменить подзапросами в разделе /* SELECT c.id_cat, c.idcategory, (подзапрос COUNT к pages с условиями), (подзапрос Max(date)  к pages с условиями) From category с */ ну и все в таком духе.

Answer (score 1):

Если запись с большей датой всегда имеет больший id, то

```
SELECT c.id_cat, c.category, COUNT(p.id_cat), MAX(p.date), MAX(p.id)
FROM category AS c 
LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON c.id_cat=p.id_cat
GROUP BY c.id_cat
ORDER BY c.id_cat DESC
```

В противном случае есть как минимум 5 способов, см статью [Группировка в MySQL](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)

Comment: Я изначально хотел привязать самый свежую запись к самому последнему id, но ведь не факт - вдруг я по каким-то причинам изменю дату записи? тогда нарушится соответствие.